# Uncaught TypeError: $.initNamespaceStorage is not a function magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, jquery, requirejs

Some functionality is not working properly and it shows some errors in console

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you managed to fix the problem? I have the same error, it appears randomly on magento frontend version 2.2.x after i clear the cache

Comment: @Miciej have you found solution?

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Comment: I think this is a jquery version problem, mostly in DHL module and for my case a vendor module for special christmas effect also causing this, check if you theme already loading certain jquery version module in the head part.